# Use of the word "Compatibility"

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

I'm writing parameters for a software report. I need a word that means "compatible" but compatible to many different applications. Something like "multi-compatible."

Answer (score 1):

If it's cross-platform compatible, you'd write that.So, I'd write "compatible with multiple applications", 'cause that's exactly what it is, isn't it? That's how I would do it...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW you could try the commonly used phrase *"broadly compatible"* or you could be more precise and use language like: *"platform neutral, open file format"* which is often used in open standards file documentation.